# Powershell can't read xml files?

Tags: xml, file, powershell

I have a powershell script to read an xml file. This is the code

```
$configPath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'config.xml'
Write-Host $configPath
[xml]$XmlDocument = [xml](get-content $configPath)
Write-Host $XmlDocument
foreach($line in Get-Content $configPath) {
    Write-Host $line
}
```

When I print `$XmlDocument` it comes out empty string, however the file is valid because when I do the for loop to read the line one at a time, it works and prints

```
<employees>
    <employee id="101">
        <name>Frankie Johnny</name>
        <age>36</age>
    </employee>
    <employee id="102">
        <name>Elvis Presley</name>
        <age>79</age>
    </employee>
    <employee id="301">
        <name>Ella Fitzgerald</name>
        <age>102</age>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Anyone know what is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: this worked for me:  [xml]$x = '<employees>
    <employee id="101">
        <name>Frankie Johnny</name>
        <age>36</age>
    </employee>
    <employee id="102">
        <name>Elvis Presley</name>
        <age>79</age>
    </employee>
    <employee id="301">
        <name>Ella Fitzgerald</name>
        <age>102</age>
    </employee>
</employees>'

Comment: It is working fine.  `Write-Host` is just confused about what to write to the screen.  By changing `Write-Host $XmlDocument` to simply `$XmlDocument`, you will see that it prints something, though probably not what you're hoping for.

Comment: What @boxdog said. `Write-Host $XmlDocument` doesn't make much sense. What is it you actually want displayed? The XML text? Use `Write-Host $XmlDocument.OuterXml` or (better) `$XmlDocument.Save([Console]::Out)` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Write-Output`, not `Write-Host`. I tested with my own XML document and `[xml]$XmlDocument` contains data, but doesn't output anything with `Write-Host`. I'm not entirely certain why `Write-Host` doesn't print the contents of $XmlDocument but I am certain it has something to do with a pipeline oddity surrounding `Write-Host` (which interrupts the pipeline).

You should almost always avoid using `Write-Host` in favor of `Write-Output`. See also the `Write-Warning`, `Write-Verbose`, `Write-Error`, and `Write-Debug` cmdlets for outputting information to other streams other than `STDOUT` or the console host directly. See [this post for more information](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) about why you should avoid `Write-Host` when you can, and how it is considered harmful.